# Analyzing efficiency of non-recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithm, for-loop

I am trying to analyze an algorithm to estimate its time efficiency using 5 steps.

**The five steps are:**

1. Decide on parameter n indicating input size.
2. Identify algorithm’s basic operation.
3. Determine worst, average, and best case for input of size n.
4. Set up summation for C(n) reflecting algorithm’s loop
   structure.
5. Simplify summation.

**The algorithm is:**

```
Algorithm UniqueElements (A[0 … n-1)
– //Check whether all the elements in a given array are
distinct
– //Input: an array A[0 … n]
– //Output: returns “true” if all the elements in A are
distinct and “false” otherwise
for i ← 0 to n - 2 do
 for j ← i + 1 to n - 1 do
– If A[i] = A[j] return false
return true
```

**My way to solve this is:**

1. Since I'm only deciding on an input size, I chose 6.
2. I said the algorithm's basic operation is the comparison between A[i] = A[j].
3. Best case: n = 1. Worst case = 6. Average case = 3.
4. Summation:

[image]

5. Summation will be simplified to n^2

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Is your array indexing 0- or 1-based? Make up your mind!

Comment: @n.m. Sorry 0-based. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be solved as follows:

1. Decide parameter n.
   I think this is asking for what is 'n' in the equation. So here, it's the length of the input array.
2. I agree with the basic operation. The comparison A[i] == A[j].
3. Since this algorithm breaks early if two elements are the same, then we know that the **worst case** is when all elements are distinct. In this situation, we'd have two loops-- one nested in the other-- each linearly related to the input length (n).

   This means our **worst case is bounded by O(n^2)**.

   Our **average case** is calculated by summing all possible outcomes and dividing by all outcomes. This looks very similar to the summating for C(n). The sum of possible times it will take to run giving an input of length n is:

   [maths to calculate average time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI5KI.gif)
   This comes out to be **Theta(n^2)**

   Finally, **best case** time. This is almost trivial<\i>. The best case here is where the first and second items in the array are identical. This is **constant time**, so **best case is theta(1)**.
4. For this part, refer again the to linked maths.
5. I agree with your simplification here! n^2 is correct.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem size? n
2. Basic operation? if-test
3. Worst and best cases are different.

   - The best case is when the first two elements are equal then Θ(n)
   - The worst case is if array elements are unique then all sequences of
     the for loops are executed
4. The sum:

   - Cworst(n) = ∑i=0n-2∑j=i+1n-1 1
5. Solove

   - Cworst(n) = ∑i=0n-2[(n-1) - (i+1) + 1] = ∑i=0n-2[n-1- i] = ∑k=n-11k where k = n - i -1
   - Cworst(n) = ∑k=1n-1k = (n-1)(n-1+1)/2 = n(n-1)/2 ε Θ(n2)

Note for a unique array there is a minimum of n(n-1)/2 comparisons. Is this necessary, is there a better algorithm?

Yes, we could pre-sort.